# Pdflatex only works as admin in OSX Lion

Tags: osx-lion, latex

I installed MacTex on OSX Lion.  The `pdflatex` command only works if I run

`sudo pdflatex`

whereas running it without `sudo` results in "command not found."  How can I get at pdflatex without admin privileges?

After trying Nifle's suggestions, the problem persists.  I actually already had the proper addition to the path,

`/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/universal-darwin/`

in my $PATH, but even accessing this directory needed admin privileges.

Comment: can you add more information please? Nifle's idea is quite sensible, but there are more things that could be the reason. Can you please post the output for "echo $PATH", and "ls -l /usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex" ?

Comment: oh, and while we're at it :-) you say "accessing this directory needed admin privileges" - could you show a "ls -ld" for the directory chain? Maybe your user is not allowed to read or execute? Add the output of "id", too, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it's not in your path when you are a regular user. That means it's probably not installed in one of the *"usual"* places.

There are a couple of things you can do to fix this.

First you need to find out where it is installed, type `sudo which pdflatex`. This should tell you where `pdflatex` is installed.

What you could try first is to create a link to `pdflatex` in a place already in your `$PATH`. You can find out what is in your path by typing `echo $PATH`, I have chosen `/usr/local/bin` (as it's usual in the path) in my example below.

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /path/to/pdflatex
```

Another alternative is to put the directory that `pdflatex` is in into your `$PATH`. In your `.bashrc` (found in your home dir) put

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/pdflatex
export PATH
```

Then to make the changes to `.bashrc` take effect you have to do `source .bashrc`

Comment: By the way, in OS X (with MacTeX), `pdflatex` is in `/usr/texbin`. I highly doubt it's not in the usual place, as the MacTeX installer does everything automatically.

Comment: @slhck - It may be the intended place but I wouldn't say that `/usr/texbin`is a *normal* place for an application. At least not in a standard linux install.

Comment: @slhck - To clarify. I would be very annoyed if all applications polluted the `/usr/` folder with their own directories. There are better places to put apps installed by users.

Comment: Yes, it's only a symlink. To be precise, it points to `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-darwin`, however `/usr/texbin` would be in the PATH.

Comment: The pdflatex binary is at `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex`, and neither method works.  I still cannot find the command when I'm not the admin.

Comment: @Jeffrey - You say in your edit that accessing the directory requires admin priviliges. You can change the permissions on that dir with `sudo chmod -R o+x /usr/local/texlive` this should let anyone enter the dir and it's sub folders/files.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is connected to [Pref Pane Bug and other Bugs in MacTeX-2011, and Fixes](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2011/prefpane.html) ?

> Similarly, the Pref Pane cannot switch between 32 bit binaries and 64
>   bit binaries. It will appear to do so, but the **user's front end cannot find the binaries**.

<sub>(Not being on the Mac, I can only speak from theory.)</sub>